# How do I use Java Regex to find all repeating character sequences in a string?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Parsing a random string looking for repeating sequences using Java and Regex.

Consider strings:

aaabbaaacccbb

I'd like to find a regular expression that will find all the matches in the above string:

```
aaabbaaacccbb
^^^  ^^^

aaabbaaacccbb
   ^^      ^^
```

What is the regex expression that will check a string for any repeating sequences of characters and return the groups of those repeating characters such that group 1 = aaa and group 2 = bb.  Also note that I've used an example string but any repeating characters are valid:
RonRonJoeJoe
... ... ,, ,,...,,

Comment: It seems using a dictionary based string search algorithm like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) will be better as you have no idea of the pattern in the beginning.

Comment: Do you need the repeated sequence to be contiguous or not? Does "RonBobRonJoe" should return "Ron?"

Comment: What should `RonBobRonBobAbeRonBobRonBobAbe` or `XXYYXY` return?

Comment: By "repeating sequences of characters", do you mean the same thing as "sequences of repeating characters"?

Answer (score 9):

This does it:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "aaabbaaacccbb";
        find(s);
        String s1 = "RonRonRonJoeJoe .... ,,,,";
        find(s1);
        System.err.println("---");
        String s2 = "RonBobRonJoe";
        find(s2);
    }

    private static void find(String s) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\1+").matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.err.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
aaa
bb
aaa
ccc
bb
RonRonRon
JoeJoe
....
,,,,
---
```

Comment: Actually, this does not work: if you run it against RonRonJoeJoe it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @ReverendGonzo OK, I missed that in the post. I fixed it now by adding the + after the \\w

Comment: @ReverendGonzo What should be the ouput for that? There is no repeating sequence and it thus does not match anything

Comment: "Ron" repeats. I'm under the impression they don't need to be contiguous.

Comment: @ReverendGonzo OK, I get what you mean now. I was actually having the opposite feeling that they should be contiguous. OP has to clarify that.

Comment: Nope, not necessarily contiguous.

Comment: Where is it getting "ccc" as a match?

Comment: @phatfingers from the first string.

Answer (score 3):

The below should work for all requirements.  It is actually a combination of a couple of the answers here, and it will print out all of the substrings that are repeated anywhere else in the string.

I set it to only return substrings of at least 2 characters, but it can be easily changed to single characters by changing "{2,}" in the regex to "+".

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String s = "RonSamJoeJoeSamRon";
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\S{2,})(?=.*?\\1)").matcher(s);
  while (m.find())
  {
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++)
    {
      System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Output:
Ron
Sam
Joe

Comment: But How would you count the number of elements each of these strings have in the file and why is it always a kmer of 3 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `positive lookahead`  based regex:

```
((\\w)\\2+)(?=.*\\1)
```

#### Code:

```
String elem = "aaabbaaacccbb";
String regex = "((\\w)\\2+)(?=.*\\1)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(elem);
for (int i=1; matcher.find(); i++)
System.out.println("Group # " + i + " got: " + matcher.group(1));
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Group # 1 got: aaa
Group # 2 got: bb
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, though it gives subsequences as well:

(To be fair, this was built off of Guillame's code)

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    // final String s = "RonRonJoeJoe";
    // final String s = "RonBobRonJoe";
    final String s = "aaabbaaacccbb";

    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+).*\\1");

    final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    int start = 0;
    while (m.find(start)) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        start = m.toMatchResult().end(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could disregard overlap.

```
// overlapped 1 or more chars
(?=(\w{1,}).*\1)
// overlapped 2 or more chars
(?=(\w{2,}).*\1)
// overlapped 3 or more chars, etc ..
(?=(\w{3,}).*\1)
```

Or, you could consume (non-overlapped) ..

```
// 1 or more chars
(?=(\w{1,}).*\1) \1
// 2 or more chars
(?=(\w{2,}).*\1) \1
// 3 or more chars, etc ..
(?=(\w{3,}).*\1) \1
```