# How to find and replace 3 or more chars with 3 or more chars in a String Java?

Tags: java, string, replace, sequence, stringbuilder

I need to check if the line contains strings that must be
eliminated and indicate which symbols would be eliminated.
A character sequence is replaced by underscores ("*"), accordingly with the sequence length, if there are three or more contiguous characters with the same symbol. for example, the line "*, _, @, @, @, @, $, $, *, #, #,!" would be transformed into "*, _, _, _, _, _, _, $, $, _, #, #,!" After the process of elimination.
I need to do this only with String or StringBuilder, Regex, ect... (Only Basic coding of Java).
Can't use arrays also.
Thanks in advance.
This is what i tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    String linha = "##,$$$$,%%%%,@%@@@,!!!!", validos = "$#%!@";        
        for (int i = 0; i < validos.length(); i++) {
            linha = linha.replaceAll("\\" + validos.charAt(i) + "{3,}", "_");
        }
        System.out.println (linha);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that replaces a sequence with just one "_", and i don't know which chars are replaced.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're not going to write all of your code for you.

Comment: Edit that into your question and format it as code.

Comment: edit your original post, not comment

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use Java Regex to find all repeating character sequences in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287685/how-do-i-use-java-regex-to-find-all-repeating-character-sequences-in-a-string)

Comment: I allready saw that one, didn't really help me.

Comment: "_, _, @, @, @, @, $, $, , #, #,!" that example looks incorrect according to your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you can do this in many ways, and probably this is a good exercise to do by yourself. Here you have a basic implementation using just basic loop structures and nothing fancy like StringUtils libraries... Note that your previous loop implementation would have missed several occurrences of the same character repeated in different locations of `linha`.

```
static int index(String lookInStr, char lookUpChr) {
    return lookInStr.indexOf(new String(new char[] { lookUpChr, lookUpChr, lookUpChr }));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String linha = "####,@@@@@@@@,$$$$,%%%%,@%@@@,!!!!", validos = "$#%!@";
    for (int i = 0; i < validos.length(); i++) {
        char currentSearchChar = validos.charAt(i);
        do {
            int index = index(linha, currentSearchChar);
            if (index >= 0) {
                int count = -1;
                do {
                    count++;
                } while (linha.charAt(count + index) == currentSearchChar && count + index < linha.length() - 1);
                String replacementSeq = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                    replacementSeq += "-";
                }
                linha = linha.replaceAll("\\" + validos.charAt(i) + "{" + count + ",}", replacementSeq);
            }
        } while (index(linha, currentSearchChar) >= 0);
    }
    System.out.println(linha);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But still doesn't serve my purposes, i can't use "char[]", but i can work from this, it's great.

Comment: It's not the best answer sorry, Final Zero for now as the best answer,but still waiting...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to replace three characters at once, and you want three underscores instead, you are just missing this:

```
linha = linha.replaceAll("\\" + validos.charAt(i) + "{3,}", "___");
```

If you want them separated by commas:

```
linha = linha.replaceAll("\\" + validos.charAt(i) + "{3,}", "_,_,_");
```

Comment: The problem is if the sequence has 4 symbols then it should be 4 underscores, if has 5 then five underscores and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really implemented this, but this is something you may look at:

In Matcher, there is `find(int start)`, `start()` and `end()`

Have a pattern for the '3-or-more-repetitive char' (you may refer to the comment in your question).

psuedo code is something like this:

```
int lastEndingPosition = 0;
StringBuilder sb;

while (matcher can find next group) {
  // add the unmatched part
  sb.append( substring of input string from lastEndingPosition to matcher.start() ); 

  // add the matched part
  sb.append( "-" for matcher.end() - matcher.start() times);
  lastEndingPosition = matcher.end();
}
sb.append( substring of input string from lastEndingPosition to the end);
```

Probably there are some more elegant way to do this.  This is just one alternative

Comment: Thanks i will try it, but if there is a more elegant way to do this, of course i would be interested...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this splits the string into separate blocks, then checks the length of the blocks and either returns the original block, or replaces it with underscores.

```
static String convert(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        StringBuilder tempSb = new StringBuilder();

        for(; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char d = s.charAt(i);

            if(d != c) {
                i--;
                break;
            } else {
                tempSb.append(d);
            }
        }

        String t = tempSb.toString();
        if(t.length() < 3) {
            sb.append(t);
        } else {
            sb.append(repeat("_", t.length()));
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = convert("##,$$$$,%%%%,@%@@@,!!!!");
    System.out.println(x); // ##,____,____,@%___,____
}
```

And here's the simple repeat method:

```
static String repeat(String s, int repeatCount) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++) {
        sb.append(s);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks FinalZero for your answer, it really works, theres is just one problem, in the 2nd cycle for, it works, but it's incorrect to program that, you know what i mean?

Comment: Do you mean that it's "incorrect" to make a for loop that skips initializing a variable? If that makes it unusable for you, then I'm not sure what to say. Anything else you write to replace it will just be a more complicated imitation of it, or hiding it in a library function.

Comment: This was the explanantion that one of my teachers told me:  
First - 2 cycles have chained for sharing the counter.  
Second - They are adulterating the updating of cycle counter for outside the inner loop. A cycle for is a kind of cycle that is expected "well behaved", ie must not in any way change how the counter is updated, especially within the cycle!

Comment: The teachers' criteria seem pretty arbitrary; I'm interested into how they want it to be done then.