# Get an array of Strings matching a pattern from a String

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a long string let's say

```
I like this #computer and I want to buy it from #XXXMall.
```

I know the regular expression pattern is

```
Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.compile("[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\b");
```

Now i want to get all the hashtags in an array. How can i use this expression to get array of all hash tags from string something like

```
ArrayList hashtags = getArray(pattern, str)
```

Comment: Split string with space -> convert to list - > run in loop on list and fetch matched values

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use Java Regex to find all repeating character sequences in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287685/how-do-i-use-java-regex-to-find-all-repeating-character-sequences-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like?

```
private static List<String> getArray(Pattern tagMatcher, String str) {
    Matcher m = tagMatcher.matcher(str);
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(m.find()) {
        String s = m.group(); //will give you "#computer"
        s = s.substring(1); // will give you just "computer"
        l.add(s);
    }
    return l;
}
```

Also you can use `\\w-` instead of `A-Za-z0-9-_` making the regex `[#]+[\\w]+\\b`

Comment: Nice answer, Can you tell me what is `\\b` in regex doing?

Comment: @Octopus Go through [Lesson: Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) specifically [Boundary Matchers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html)

Comment: @Octopus what did he do for you to thank him for (other than a nice answer)?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html) would surely be helpful for achieving what you want.

It says:

> The find() method searches for occurrences of the regular expressions
>   in the text passed to the Pattern.matcher(text) method, when the
>   Matcher was created. If multiple matches can be found in the text, the
>   find() method will find the first, and then for each subsequent call
>   to find() it will move to the next match.
>
> The methods start() and end() will give the indexes into the text
>   where the found match starts and ends.

Example:

```
String text    =
        "This is the text which is to be searched " +
        "for occurrences of the word 'is'.";

String patternString = "is";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

int count = 0;
while(matcher.find()) {
    count++;
    System.out.println("found: " + count + " : "
            + matcher.start() + " - " + matcher.end());
}
```

You got the hint now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

```
Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.compile("#+[-\\w]+\\b");
Matcher m = tagMatcher.matcher(stringToMatch);

ArrayList<String> hashtags = new ArrayList<>();

while (m.find()) {
    hashtags.add(m.group());
}
```

I took the liberty of simplifying your regex. `#` does not need to be in a character class. `[A-Za-z0-9_]` is the same as `\w`, so `[A-Za-z0-9-_]` is the same as `[-\w]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
String val="I like this #computer and I want to buy it from #XXXMall.";
String REGEX = "(?<=#)[A-Za-z0-9-_]+";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(val);
while(matcher.find()){
    list.add(matcher.group());
}
```

`(?<=#)` **Positive Lookbehind** - Assert that the character `#` literally  be matched.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code for getting the names

```
    String saa = "#{akka}nikhil#{kumar}aaaaa";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("#\\{(.*?)\\}");
    Matcher m = regex.matcher(saa);
    while(m.find()) {
        String s = m.group(1); 
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

It will print

```
akka
kumar
```